# android : checkbox problem?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-listview

I'm trying to select all the checkbox in list. Why am getting particular checkbox only true. Code is : -

```
            ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        for(int i=0; i < listview.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            AbsoluteLayout itemLayout = (AbsoluteLayout)listview.getChildAt(i);
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            if(cb.isChecked())
            {
                cb.setChecked(false);
            }
            else
            {
                cb.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: AbsoluteLayout is deprecated DO NOT USE IT

Comment: if you need to select all checkboxes why if else.just write cb.setChecked(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use this with two buttons like `selectall` & `unselectall`

```
    public void checkallbtn_Click(View view)
{
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.backuplist);
    CheckBox cb;
    try
    {
        for(int i=0;i<lv.getCount();i++)
        {
            cb = (CheckBox)lv.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            if(!cb.isChecked())
            {
                cb.setChecked(true);
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
public void uncheckallbtn_Click(View view)
{
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.backuplist);
    try
    {
        for(int i=0;i<lv.getCount();i++)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)lv.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            if(cb.isChecked())
            {
                cb.setChecked(false);
            }
        }           
    }catch(Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand the question fully..

But I belive:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
```

will always return the same CheckBox (the one with id checkBox1), even if you have multiple checkboxes in your list.

Comment: No,Not correct.Look carefully to the code.It is accessing each list item as the layout and from that it is accessing checkbox.So you can't say it is the same checkbox all the time

Comment: Only on the top of his listview the checkbox is modified. That is what i referred to. No need to access the CheckBox thru his layout. Each row has represents View as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
   for(int i=0; i < listview.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)listview.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);  //if the child views are properly populated in each row item then on this particular positon ChBox will be found and instantiated
            if(cb.isChecked())
            {
                cb.setChecked(false);
            }
            else
            {
                cb.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
```